# Find the maximum area of rectangle between y-axis , $f(x)=x^3 , y=32$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area, maxima-minima

[image: Maximum area of rectangle]

Find the maximum area of rectangle between the $y$-axis , $f(x)=x^3 , y=32$

Comment: You need to express the length, width and area of the rectangle in terms of $x$ and find the value of $x$ which gives the maximum area.

Comment: as far as i went , i considered rectangle with maximum area is square , if side length is L , so point B coordinate is B(L,32-L) the same as B(X,32-X) , it lies on the curve so it verifies it , i did the algebra and got a number , but Iam not sure  , and the method is still so loosy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B(t,t^3)$, where $t>0$ and $t^3<32$.

Thus, $AB=t$ and $BC=32-t^3$.

Hence, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$S_{ABCD}=t(32-t^3)=48-(t^4-32t+48)=$$
$$=48-(t^4+16+16+16-32t)\leq48-\left(4\sqrt[4]{t^4\cdot16^3}-32t\right)=48.$$
The equality occurs for $t=2$.

Id est, the answer is $48$.

By calculus it's harder:

Let $f(t)=32t-t^4$, where $0<t<\sqrt[3]{32}$.

Hence, $f'(t)=32-4t^3=4(2-t)(4+2t+t^2)$.

Since $f'(t)>0$ for $0<t<2$ and $f'(t)<0$ for $2<t<\sqrt[3]{32}$,

we obtain $t_{max}=2$ and the answer is $f(2)=48$.

Comment: great , but can i ask you if there is a way , using calculus , i hadnt studied am-gm , and its a calculus test , ik u already answered it , but i hope you can help me with that

Answer (score 1):

let one sidelength of rectangle be $a$ then we get the area as $$A=a\cdot (32-f(a))$$ if $$f(x)=x^3$$ then we have $$A=a\cdot \left(32-a^3\right)$$

Comment: any explanation , + its a test sample , and Iam supposed to give numerical result

Comment: What you have left is to derive $A(a)$, then solve the equation $A'(a)=0$ ...

Comment: A=a⋅(32−f(a)) where this function came from